# Connect iPad to company Ethernet LAN via USB bridge

Tags: linux, networking, ipad

My Linux Ubuntu 16.04 PC is connected to a very simple office Ethernet LAN via Ethernet. IPs are manually configured on each PC, but we are free to change them as we want (I've full root access to the PC and the office gateway is a residential router with DHCP disabled).

Each PC can Ethernet "see" each other.

I need to add an iPad to the mix, but there isn't a Wi-Fi.

Is it possible to **connect the iPad to my PC via USB and have the PC act as a bridge to the Ethernet for it**? I'm interested in media and network access only: I'll then configure the iPad IP manually.

Edit: I don't have a hardware Lightning-to-Ethernet adapter for the iPad. Just the Lightning-to-USB provided cable.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, when I use a so called search engine, my first result seems to be what you descripe.

Comment: @davidbaumann Would you please be so kind to point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While this is quite a list of things you’ll need, setting it all up takes less than 30 seconds:

1. First off, disable WiFi on your iPad, as well as cellular data if it’s an LTE model.
2. Plug one end of the Ethernet cable into a free port on your router, and the other end into the Ethernet port on the USB Ethernet Adapter.
3. Connect the USB end of the adapter to any of the USB ports on the USB hub.
4. Connect the USB cable that came with your USB hub to the hub. The cable should have a smaller connector on one end and the port for it should be on the back of the hub.
5. Connect the power cable for the USB hub to the hub and plug the other end into a wall outlet.
6. Connect the USB end of the Lighting to USB Adapter to the other end of the USB cable that came with your USB hub.
7. Lastly, plug the Lightning end of the adapter into your iPad.

Comment: I don't have a hardware Lightning-to-Ethernet adapter for the iPad. Just the Lightning-to-USB provided cable.